# how to edit numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code is

```
a = np.array([[0, 7], [1, 7], [2, 7], [3, 7], [4, 3], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 7]])
print(a)
print(np.shape(a))


[[0, 7]
 [1, 7]
 [2, 7]
 [3, 7]
 [4, 3]
 [5, 3]
 [6, 2]
 [7, 7]]

(8, 2)
```

and I want to make like this

(column is bigger than 6)

```
([[0, 7],
 [1, 7],
 [2, 7],
 [3, 7],
 [7, 7]])
```

how to make the code?

Comment: the terms you need to search for are "indexing and slicing". One of the first examples here should help: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#indexing-and-slicing

Comment: There are no values “greater than 7”

Answer (score 0):

You should create a boolean mask and use to select only rows with column values greater than 6

```py
mask = a[:,1] > 6
out = a[mask]
print(out)
```

---

```
[[0 7]
 [1 7]
 [2 7]
 [3 7]
 [7 7]]
```